I am getting multiple tabs of figure when i input the year... i need only one animated tab and planet img must show in different tab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import solar_system_ephemeris, get_body_barycentric
from astropy.coordinates import CartesianRepresentation
from astropy import units as u
from transformers import pipeline
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from PIL import Image
import mplcursors

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def build_cnn_model(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
        MaxPooling1D(2),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    return model

def analyze_orbital_data(orbital_data, labels):
    cnn_model = build_cnn_model(input_shape=orbital_data.shape[1:])
    cnn_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    cnn_model.fit(orbital_data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
    return cnn_model

def compute_positions_and_orbits(year):
    positions = {}
    orbits = {}
    
    start_time = Time(f'{year}-01-01', scale='utc')
    end_time = start_time + 365 * u.day  # Simulate one year of data

    with solar_system_ephemeris.set('builtin'):
        planets = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars', 'jupiter', 'saturn', 'uranus', 'neptune']

        for planet_name in planets:
            times = Time(np.linspace(start_time.jd, end_time.jd, 1000), format='jd')
            planet = get_body_barycentric(planet_name, times)
            positions[planet_name] = planet.represent_as(CartesianRepresentation).xyz.value
            orbits[planet_name] = planet.represent_as(CartesianRepresentation).xyz.value

    return positions, orbits

def update(frame, current_year, positions, orbits, planet_images):
    plt.cla()
    plt.xlabel('X (AU)')
    plt.ylabel('Y (AU)')
    plt.title(f'Planetary Orbits and Positions in {current_year}')
    plt.gca().set_facecolor('black')  # Set background color to black

    for i, (planet_name, orbit) in enumerate(orbits.items()):
        x_orbit, y_orbit, _ = orbit
        x_pos, y_pos, _ = positions[planet_name]

        # Plot full orbit path
        plt.plot(x_orbit, y_orbit, color='white', alpha=0.3)

        # Load planet image and resize
        planet_image_path = planet_images.get(planet_name)
        if planet_image_path:
            planet_image = Image.open(planet_image_path)
            planet_image = planet_image.resize((500, 500))  # Resize image for better visibility

            # Plot the planet image at the current position
            plt.imshow(planet_image, extent=(x_pos[frame] - 0.5, x_pos[frame] + 0.5, y_pos[frame] - 0.5, y_pos[frame] + 0.5), alpha=0.8, label=planet_name)

    # Define the hover function
    def on_hover(event):
        planet_name = "Earth"
        planet_image = "earth.jpg"
        display_zoomed_image(planet_name, planet_image)

    # Connect hover event to the plot
    mplcursors.cursor(hover=True).connect("add", on_hover)

    # Set aspect ratio to equal and adjust axis limits for the animation space
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.xlim(-50, 50)  # Adjust x-axis limits for the animation space
    plt.ylim(-50, 50)  # Adjust y-axis limits for the animation space

    plt.show()

def display_zoomed_image(planet_name, planet_image):
    print(f"Hovering over planet: {planet_name}")
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(planet_image)
    ax.set_title(planet_name)
    plt.show()

def animate(year):
    positions, orbits = compute_positions_and_orbits(year)
    num_frames = len(next(iter(positions.values()))[0])  # Number of frames based on position data length

    # Load planet images for each planet
    planet_images = {
        'mercury': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\mercury.jpeg",
        'venus': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\venus.jpeg",
        'earth': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\earth.jpeg",
        'mars': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\mars.jpeg",
        'jupiter': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\jupyter.png",
        'saturn': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\saturn.png",
        'uranus': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\uranus.jpeg",
        'neptune': r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\planet imgs\neptune.jpg"
    }

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=num_frames, fargs=(year, positions, orbits, planet_images),
                                  interval=50, repeat=False)

    plt.show()

def process_user_input(input_text):
    nlp = pipeline("ner", grouped_entities=True)
    entities = nlp(input_text)
    year = None

    for entity in entities:
        if entity['entity'] == 'DATE':
            try:
                year = int(entity['word'])
                break
            except ValueError:
                continue

    return year

def main():
    while True:
        year_input = input("Enter a year between 1900 and 2040: ")

        try:
            year = int(year_input)
            if 1900 <= year <= 2040:
                animate(year)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid year. Please enter a year between 1900 and 2040.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid year.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


i have tried troubleshooting and working on instances but the result is not cmg as i want it...
I'm struggling to display planet images correctly during the animation. The orbits of the planets show up fine, but the images themselves don't appear at their expected positions. I've verified the image paths and used PIL to resize them, but the images still don't show. Additionally, the hover function I've defined doesn't trigger as intended. Any insights or suggestions would be helpful!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The issues with your code that need to be addressed to display the planet images correctly during the animation and to trigger the hover function properly. The positioning of the planet images might be incorrect due to the way you're setting the extent parameter in the imshow function. Instead of directly using the position values, you might need to adjust them based on the size of the image. he hover function on_hover is currently hardcoded to display information about Earth. You need to update this function to accept parameters for the planet name and image path.
